# Order By month and year in ORACLE with sum

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure and the select statement is:

```
  SELECT COUNT(IDENTIFIER) AS      TOTALORDER,SUM(FT.ACTUALORDER01+FT.ACTUALORDER02+FT.ACTUALORDER03+FT.ACTUALOR      DER04) AS TOTALORDER,
  SUM(TOTALPENDING) AS PENDING,
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE),'MonthYYYY') AS "Month-Year"
                                                            FROM FTORDER      FT FULL JOIN FSDPENDING FS
                                                            ON      FS.IDENTIFIER=FT.ORDERNUMBER
                                                            AND     FT.ORDERDATE=FS.ORDERDATETIME
                                                            AND FT.ORDREcode=FS.ORDERcode
                                                            AND FT.sequence=FS.sequence
                                                            AND FT.recordstatus=FS.recordstatus
              WHERE TRUNC(FORDERDATETIME) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','dd/mon/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-2015','dd/mon/yyyy')
                                                            AND TORDERNUMBER NOT LIKE ('-%') 
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE),'MonthYYYY')
    ORDER BY "Month-Year"
 ;
```

this shows the sum total for every month But I need to order the result by month and year coz my result shown like:

```
April 2013 
February 2013 
January 2013 
June 2013 
March 2013 
May 2013
```

What is the solution in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DATE),'MonthYYYY')

There are couple of things incorrect.

Never apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE** column. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date. For **date-arithmetic**, leave the date as it is.

You are currently sorting the **string**, since **TO_CHAR** converts the date into string.

You could do it as:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MON-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(hiredate,'MONTH')
  2  FROM emp
  3  GROUP BY TRUNC(hiredate,'MONTH')
  4  ORDER BY TRUNC(hiredate,'MONTH');

TRUNC(HIRED
-----------
1980-DEC-01
1981-FEB-01
1981-APR-01
1981-MAY-01
1981-JUN-01
1981-SEP-01
1981-NOV-01
1981-DEC-01
1982-JAN-01
1982-DEC-01
1983-JAN-01

11 rows selected.
```

NOTE : The alter session statement is only to display the date in desired format.

Comment: PROBLEM is date is in vchar format so i need to convert to_date

Comment: @AssadAmjad You should always mention the **DATA TYPE**. Anyway, it is first a design issue. Secondly, how do you manage to store dates in such format?

Comment: well this software desgin the tabels .. so i handle with to_date function like i mention in my query

Comment: @AssadAmjad As a workaround, instead of `hiredate` in my example, just use `TO_DATE(your_date, 'format')` And everything will remain same. TRUNC would work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Change the format of your to_date to (YYYY-MM) and then order by this, either DESC or ASC to get it in the order you want. Currently it is ordering it alphabetically based on the Month name.

Comment: its work but months in numeric format and i need in alphabetic format and British  date formate